# Firebase Functions: functions is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In index.js, I have:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  const original = snapshot.val();
  console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
  const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
  // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
  // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
  // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
  return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
});
```

I literally copy-pasted the code from:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Somehow, when I deploy using

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I get:

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>   ReferenceError: functions is not defined
>       at Object. (/home/[USERNAME HERE]/functions/index.js:1:87)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at /usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:21:11
>       at Object. (/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:75:3)

What's going on, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Does your `index.js` contain `const functions = require('firebase-functions');`?

Comment: Trying that now...

Comment: I'm stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [setup documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import_the_required_modules_and_initialize) explains, you need to import required modules and initialize the app:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

Comment: I thought it should be: `const functions = require('firebase/functions');` -- Slash ("/") and not Dash ("-")?